# Error al ejecutar python manage.py runserver: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 4: invalid continuation byte"

Tags: python, django

estoy intentando hacer una aplicacion en python usando django, pero al ejecutar el comando `python manage.py runserver` me aparece el siguiente error (en los path, he puesto __ porque en el error sale mi nombre, aún así me he asegurado de que esa carpeta no tuviera ningún carácter raro como un espacio o una letra con acento):

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 11, 2021 - 15:50:47
Django version 3.0.5, using settings 'InstaGraffiti.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\____\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\____\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\____\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\____\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 138, in inner_run
    run(self.addr, int(self.port), handler,
  File "C:\Users\____\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 206, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "C:\Users\____\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 67, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\____\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\____\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\____\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\server.py", line 140, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Users\____\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 791, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 4: invalid continuation byte
```

El valor que se supone que no puede decodificar parece ser una 'á' pero no encuentro en ningún lado donde puede estar, además el valor de "name" que no puede decodificar es "127.0.0.1".

Cualquier idea que pueda solucionarlo o ayudarme a encontrarlo, me serviría. También he de decir que antes, la parte donde aparece mi nombre sí que contenía antes una 'á', pero he cambiado el nombre de la carpeta, con sus respectivos valores de registro y las variables de entorno

Comment: Puedes comprobar el valor de `hostname` desde la consola de python?

Comment: Parece que ahí está el problema, ese es el nombre del equipo en sí, no?

Comment: Mira a ver si en `/etc/hosts` hay una entrada que asigne un nombre a la IP 127.0.0.1 y si es ese nombre el que tiene la á.

Comment: Si lanzas el server con `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080` tienes el mismo problema con el host?

Comment: Con ese comando seguía dando error. He cambiado el nombre del dispositivo que sí tenía una á y parece que eso lo ha solucionado. Muchas gracias